# Converse of Spectral Theorem for Compact Self-Adjoint Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

If I have a bounded linear operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$ whose eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis for $H$ and whose corresponding eigenvalues go to $0$ then is $A$ compact and self-adjoint?

I ask because I want to prove that $A$ defined on an orthonormal basis $\{e_k\}$ as $Ae_k=e_k/(k^2+1)$ is compact and self-adjoint. I know that it is, but I'm just wondering if appealing to the spectral theorem is valid. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's valid.  In particular, we can define $A$ as the limit of finite-rank operators (with respect to the operator norm).  $A$ inherits self-adjointness from the sequence since $A \mapsto A^*$ is operator-norm continuous.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, this holds for all $A$ with eigenvectors that form an onb and eigenvalues that go to 0 and not just for the explicit operator $A$ I gave, correct?

Comment: Yep!${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $A $ is compact. By considering truncations of $A $ that are zero on $e_k $ for $k\geq n $, you can write $A $ as a limit of finite-rank operators.

Comment: Do you mean a limit of finite rank operators, or perhaps a sum of rank-one operators?

Comment: Corrected, thanks.